# Show that the annulus $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 3$ is positively invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, self-learning, invariance, set-invariance

> Given the planar dynamical system
>
> $$\dot x = x - y - x^3, \\ \dot y = x + y - y^3$$
>
> show this is positively invariant in the annulus $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 3$. Hints:
>
> $$x^4 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)^2 − 2x^2y^2$$
>
> $$x^4 + y^4 = \frac 12 (x^2 + y^2)^2 + \frac 12 (x^2 - y^2)^2$$

**My attempt**:

I am really unsure whether what I am doing is correct or not, but I seem to get the right answer.

$$V:= x^2 + y^2$$

Take the derivative,

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}$$

which gives

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \pmatrix{2x \\ 2y} \cdot \pmatrix{x-y-x^3 \\ x+y-y^3} = 2x^2 - 2xy - 2x^4 + 2xy + 2y^2 - 2y^4 \\ = 2(x^2 + y^2 -x^4 - y^4)$$

By using the 2 hints given I get that

$$2(x^2 + y^2 -x^4 - y^4) = 2(x^2 + y^2) - 2(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 4x^2y^2$$

and

$$2(x^2 + y^2 -x^4 - y^4) = 2(x^2+y^2) - (x^2+y^2)^2 - (x^2-y^2)$$

Converting these into polar coordinates will give

$$2r^2(1-r^2) + 4x^2y^2 \geq 0$$

when $r^2=1$, and

$$2r^2 \left( 1-\frac{r^2}{2} \right) - (x^2-y^2)^2 < 0$$

when $r^2=3$. Therefore can conclude from this that they are both pointing inwards.

Even though I am getting the right answer, I don't know if my methodology is correct. The place where I am not confident is when I call $V := x^2+y^2$ and then take like the orbital derivative.

Comment: Yes your  argument  is  completely true. Then  we  conclude that  the  system has  a (unique) periodic orbit in the  annular region(A  consequence of  Poincare  Bendixon theorem)

Comment: The uniqueness is  a  consequence of the fact that the  divergence of the field  is negative  in the  annular region

Comment: The issue I had was that  am taking the Orbital derivative? And I don't fully understand why I should be taking that and how this shows that the annulus is invariant

Comment: Lets look at your  question geometrically. You  have  an equation $x'=P,\;y'=Q$. so  at each point  $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we  place a vector $(P(x,y), Q(x,y))$. This  vector  initiate  from $(x,y)$. Your  computation shows that your  vector fields on the boundary of the annular region   is toward interior.  Now the invariance of the  annular region uner the flow  of the  vector  field  means that every  solution starting the  annular region will remain in this  region forever. Institutionally,  it  is  obvious. Because the direction of the vector fields on the boundary is  counted ....

Comment: .....as  obstructions (and  forbidding instruments as spear)  against people  who leave in the annular region and wish to leave that region.

Comment: In my 2 previous comment  I  correct "Intuition"-ally!

Comment: To  be  more  precise, the  invariance of the  annular region is  a  consequence of  "uniqueness"property  for  the  solutions of  differential equations. In the other words, solutions(orbits) starting the  boundary, enter  the  annular region.

Comment: I recommend to look at the concept "local section" in the  book of  Hirsch, Smale, Linear algebra  differential equation and  dynamical  system. The  concept you  are considering is a "Local section" and  a  transversality concept. There is  a  lemma  in the  above  book which convince you that your  computation implies the invariance property.

Comment: Ok great. Will take a look at that now. Thank you!

Comment: @Grabow  You are well come. I remain for  more conversation if it is  necessary.(Conversation via  comment or MSE chat or email).

Comment: Here is a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPETv.jpg) of the vector field and of the annulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found that 
$$
2V(1-V)\le \dot V\le V(2-V)
$$
Treating these differential inequalities in the Bernoulli fashion now divide by $V^2$ to get for $U=1/V$
$$
2U-2\le -\dot U\le 2U-1\\
1\le\dot U+2U\le 2\\
U_0e^{-2t}+\frac12(1-e^{-2t})\le U(t)\le U_0e^{-2t}+(1-e^{-2t})\\
\frac{1}{1+(1/V_0-1)e^{-2t}}\le V(t)\le \frac2{1+(2/V_0-1)e^{-2t}}
$$
which shows that from any position (except the origin) the solution curve will move to the annulus $1\le V\le 2$.